# Android Application Design - Accessing website data

Tags: android

I am new to Android development and am interested in working out a design of an application. I am however, unfamiliar with the best way to handle what I want to do. I am interested in obtaining information from my band's Joomla website and placing it into an Android application. At the moment I'd like to get News articles posted and potentially other information that I create on the site. I was thinking of doing this by setting up RSS feeds for the website. Would it be better to somehow access the data directly by connecting to the database? I don't know PHP so I can't develop a webservice to access the content. Any ideas?

Comment: This question is asked every week, apparently. Please search for "Android connect database". Examples: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3712862/android-app-to-connect-to-backend-database-website , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2998468/connect-android-application-to-remote-data ...

Answer (score 1):

In this case I think using the RSS feed would work just fine and it saves the hassle of connecting directly to the database. Just use any XML parser. I think Jsoup would work:

http://jsoup.org/